# Creating season variable by month with dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that has a variable called month, which each month as a character. Is there a way with dplyr to combine some months to create a season variable? I have tried the following but got an error:

```
data %>%
  mutate(season = ifelse(month[1:3], "Winter", ifelse(month[4:6], "Spring", 
                     ifelse(month[7:9], "Summer", 
                            ifelse(month[10:12], "Fall", NA)))))
```

With error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Column `season` must be length 100798 (the number of rows) or one, not 3
```

I am new to R so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct syntax should be

```
data %>% mutate(season = ifelse(month %in% 10:12, "Fall",
                               ifelse(month %in% 1:3, "Winter",
                                      ifelse(month %in% 4:6, "Spring",
                                             "Summer"))))
```

**Edit**: probably a better way to get the job done

[Astronomical Seasons](https://www.globalweatherclimatecenter.com/weather-education/the-difference-between-astronomical-and-meteorological-seasons)

```
temp_data %>%
  mutate(
    season = case_when(
      month %in% 10:12 ~ "Fall",
      month %in%  1:3  ~ "Winter",
      month %in%  4:6  ~ "Spring",
      TRUE ~ "Summer"))
```

Meteorological Seasons

```
temp_data %>%
  mutate(
    season = case_when(
      month %in%  9:11 ~ "Fall",
      month %in%  c(12, 1, 2)  ~ "Winter",
      month %in%  3:5  ~ "Spring",
      TRUE ~ "Summer"))
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! I think I was confused about brackets usage!

Comment: I added another (better) way to do it using `case_when`

Comment: 1:3 are not the correct months for Winter, aren't they? Probably it should be something like `month %in% 9:11 ~ "Fall"`,  `month %in% c(1,2,12)  ~ "Winter"`, `month %in%  3:5  ~ "Spring"`.

Comment: @VasylLaver: What you are referring to is [meteorological season](https://www.globalweatherclimatecenter.com/weather-education/the-difference-between-astronomical-and-meteorological-seasons). OP used astronomical season definition. Let me add that to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

When there are multiple key/value, we can do a join with a key/val dataset

```
keyval <- data.frame(month = month.abb, 
      season = rep(c("Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall"), each = 3),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

left_join(data, keyval)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using `dplyr::recode` or functions from `forcats`. I think this is the simplest method here:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date
data <- tibble(month = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))

data %>%
  mutate(
    season = fct_collapse(
      .f = month,
      Spring = c("Mar", "Apr", "May"),
      Summer = c("Jun", "Jul", "Aug"),
      Autumn = c("Sep", "Oct", "Nov"),
      Winter = c("Dec", "Jan", "Feb")
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 12 x 2
#>    month season
#>    <chr> <fct> 
#>  1 Jan   Winter
#>  2 Feb   Winter
#>  3 Mar   Spring
#>  4 Apr   Spring
#>  5 May   Spring
#>  6 Jun   Summer
#>  7 Jul   Summer
#>  8 Aug   Summer
#>  9 Sep   Autumn
#> 10 Oct   Autumn
#> 11 Nov   Autumn
#> 12 Dec   Winter
```

Created on 2018-04-06 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: There are default `month.abb` and `month.name` vars you can use to save some typing