# using tidyverse for create variable rather than base R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data which has admission month. I would like to do the same in a tidy way

```
df$qrtr[df$amonth %in% 1:3]<- "a"    
df$qrtr[df$amonth %in% 4:6] <- "b"    
df$qrtr[df$amonth %in% 7:9]<- "c"    
df$qrtr[df$amonth %in% 10:12]<- "d"
```

Comment: Not exactly the same but might give you an idea https://stackoverflow.com/a/49702124/786542

Answer (score 0):

As @Tung suggested, dplyr's case_when can be used:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(qtr = case_when(
   .$amonth %in% 1:3) ~ 'a',
   .$amonth %in% 4:6) ~ 'b',
   .$amonth %in% 7:9) ~ 'c',
   .$amonth %in% 10:12) ~ 'd',
   TRUE ~ NA))
```

A slightly more readable approach is a combination. The dplyr method of piping is to improve readability, so a combination could be done as:

```
seasons <- rep(c('a','b','c','d'), each=3)
df %>% mutate(qtr=seasons[amonth])
```

Which is perhaps to leap over the burn to fetch water, as the second line is equivalent to `df$qtr <- seasons[df$amonth]`. But, if combined with other operations, one or the other is more fitting.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use lubridate for this? if the "amonth" column is a date object you could

```
df %>% mutate(qtr = lubridate::floor_date(amonth, "3 month"))
```