# Using "IF ELSE" in R to create a new categorical variable column from a numeric variable column

Tags: r, if-statement, calculated-columns, categorical-data

I've browsed the other posts and tried to implement it in my solution, but getting tripped up on what I am doing wrong.

I have a column with variable "MONTH" in the DF "bostoncrimes_zip" which is numeric for the month (1 - 12)

I am attempting to create a column with name "SEASON" to add the corresponding season, given the month in the "MONTH" column.

My code is below. Thank you!

```
bostoncrimes_zips$Season <- as.factor(ifelse((bostoncrimes_zips$MONTH == 12) | ((bostoncrimes_zips$MONTH) > 2 & (bostoncrimes_zips$MONTH <= 5))), 'Winter',
                 ifelse((bostoncrimes_zips$MONTH > 2) & (bostoncrimes_zips$MONTH <= 5)), 'Spring', 
                 ifelse((bostoncrimes_zips$MONTH > 5) & (bostoncrimes_zips$MONTH <= 8)), 'Summer', 
                 ifelse((bostoncrimes_zips$MONTH > 8) & (bostoncrimes_zips$MONTH <= 11)), 'Fall')
```

When I run the code, this is the error message I get

"Error in as.factor(ifelse((bostoncrimes_zips$MONTH == 12) | ((bostoncrimes_zips$MONTH) >  :
unused arguments ("Winter", ifelse((bostoncrimes_zips$MONTH > 2) & (bostoncrimes_zips$MONTH <= 5)), "Spring", ifelse((bostoncrimes_zips$MONTH > 5) & (bostoncrimes_zips$MONTH <= 8)), "Summer", ifelse((bostoncrimes_zips$MONTH > 8) & (bostoncrimes_zips$MONTH <= 11)), "Fall")"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49702002/creating-season-variable-by-month-with-dplyr-in-r

Comment: This would likely benefit from a previous answer from akrun that suggested the use of `cut` to greatly simplify the code/logic and readability of your code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814912/error-replacement-has-x-rows-data-has-y

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by r2evans, the `cut` function is probably a better solution.  Here is a compact example mapped to your problem.  Note that the output includes NA values that you can filter out.

```
month <- 1:12
df <- data.frame(month = month)
breaks <- c(0, 2, 5, 8, 11, 12)
labels <- c('winter', 'spring', 'summer', 'fall', 'winter')
df$seasons <- cut(df$month, breaks, labels)
df
   month seasons
1      1  winter
2      2  winter
3      3  spring
4      4  spring
5      5  spring
6      6  summer
7      7  summer
8      8  summer
9      9    fall
10    10    fall
11    11    fall
12    12  winter
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to nesting and wordiness, you have extra unneeded parentheses and missed a required third argument on last `ifelse` condition. Consider `with` or `within` as context manager for column reference and indenting lines to better manage the nested consitions. Even try `%in%` given small range of integer values.

```r
bostoncrimes_zips$Season <- with(
    bostomcrimes_zips,
    as.factor(
      ifelse(MONTH == 12 | MONTH == 1 | MONTH == 2, 'Winter', 
         ifelse((MONTH > 2) & (MONTH <= 5), 'Spring', 
           ifelse((MONTH > 5) & (MONTH <= 8), 'Summer', 
             ifelse((MONTH > 8) & (MONTH <= 11), 'Fall', NA) 
           )
         )
      )
    )
)
```

```r
bostoncrimes_zips <- within(
    bostomcrimes_zips, {
    SEASON <- as.factor(
      ifelse(MONTH %in% c(12, 1, 2), 'Winter', 
         ifelse(MONTH %in% c(3, 4, 5), 'Spring', 
           ifelse(MONTH %in% c(6, 7, 8), 'Summer', 
             ifelse(MONTH %in% c(9, 10, 11), 'Fall', NA) 
           )
         )
      )
    )
})
```